# Get option label associated with admin store in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, magento-2.1, attribute-options, labels

I want to go through all options of attributes configured for filtering and output the label of the Admin Store View. I only managed to get the Default Store View (store_id 1) label with the following code:

```
$coll = $this->_objectManager->create(\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Attribute\Collection::class);
$coll->addIsFilterableFilter();
$layeredNavAttributes = $coll->load()->getItems();

foreach ($layeredNavAttributes AS $attr) {
    $options = $attr->getSource()->getAllOptions();
    foreach ($options AS $option) {
      echo $option['label'];
    }
}
```

How can I get the labels of the Admin Store View (store_id 0) instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some more trying, I came to the answer myself. Just call the `setStoreId()` method on each attribute. So the code to get the Admin labels looks like this:

```
$coll = $this->_objectManager->create(\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Attribute\Collection::class);
$coll->addIsFilterableFilter();
$layeredNavAttributes = $coll->load()->getItems();

foreach ($layeredNavAttributes AS $attr) {
    $attr->setStoreId(0);
    $options = $attr->getSource()->getAllOptions();
    foreach ($options AS $option) {
      echo $option['label'];
    }
}
```

Comment: Argh... Crazy Magento with it's magic methods! I thought it would be something like this, but `Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute` doesn't have a `setStoreId()`-method. However, it has a `setData()` / magic methods so your solution is correct. But I sure hope that those magic methods get deprecated soon.

Comment: how to use setter here? I am using $attr->setOptions([$option]);  , it is storing only to admin